# 2D Sorting with NumPy - sort 1 row and have the other follow the sorting

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, scipy

Say I have a NumPy array:

```
[[4 9 2]
 [5 1 3]]
```

I want to sort the bottom row of this array, but have the top row follow the sorting, such that I get:

```
[[9 2 4]
 [1 3 5]]
```

I know that you can sort like this using the sorted() function, but that requires input and output of lists.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[4,9,2],[5,1,3]])
idx = np.argsort(a[1])
```

Now you can use idx to index your array:

```
b=a[:,idx]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!  That solution was a lot simpler than I was expecting.  I was reading through the numpy argsort() examples, and was probably over-thinking this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only (efficient) solution I can think of needs a copy of the original array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[4,9,2],[5,1,3]])
idx = np.argsort(a[1])
```

So, that `idx` is the index of the *sorted* column.

```
c = a.copy()
for i in range(len(idx)):
  a[:,i] = c[:,idx[i]]
```

That should be reasonably fast, but, of course, wastes some memory.